# grep inside less?

Tags: bash, grep, logs, less

I'm currently sifting through a lot of unfamiliar logs looking for some issues.  The first file I look at is Events.log, and I get at least three pages in `less` which appear to display the same event at different times – an event that appears to be fairly benign.
I would like to filter this event out, and currently I quit `less` and do something like

```
grep -v "event text" Events.log | less
```

This now brings a number of other common, uninteresting events that I would also like to filter out.  Is there a way I can `grep -v` *inside* of `less`?  Rather than having to do

```
egrep -v "event text|something else|the other thing|foo|bar" Events.log | less
```

It strikes me as a useful feature when looking at any kind of log file – and if `less` isn't the tool, is there another with the qualities I seek?  Just a `less`-style viewer with built in `grep`.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

`less` has very powerful pattern matching.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

> `&pattern`
>
>   Display only lines which match the
>   `pattern`
>   ;
>     lines which do not match the
>   `pattern`
>   are not displayed.  If
>   `pattern`
>   is empty
>     (if you type
>   `&`
>   immediately followed by
>   <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>   ),
>     any filtering is turned off, and all lines are displayed. 
>     While filtering is in effect,
>     an ampersand is displayed at the beginning of the prompt,
>     as a reminder that some lines in the file may be hidden.
>
> Certain characters are special as in the `/` command<sup>†</sup>:
>
> `^N` or `!`
>
>   Display only lines which do NOT match the
>   `pattern`
>   .
>
> `^R`
>
>   Don't interpret regular expression metacharacters;
>     that is, do a simple textual comparison.
>
> ____________
>   <sup>†</sup> Certain characters are special
>   if entered at the beginning of the `pattern`;
>   they modify the type of search
>   rather than become part of the `pattern`.

(Of course `^N` and `^R` represent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, respectively.)

So, for example, `&dns` will display only lines that match the pattern `dns`,
and `&!dns` will filter out (exclude) those lines,
displaying only lines that don't match the pattern.

It is noted in the description of the `/` command that

>   The
>   `pattern`
>   is a regular expression,
>     as recognized by the regular expression library supplied by your system.

So

- `&eth[01]`  will display lines containing `eth0` or `eth1`
- `&arp.*eth0` will display lines containing `arp` followed by `eth0`
- `&arp|dns`  will display lines containing `arp` or `dns`

And the `!` can invert any of the above. 
So the command you would want to use for the example in your question is:

```
&!event text|something else|the other thing|foo|bar
```

Also use `/pattern` and `?pattern`
to search (and `n`/`N` to go to next/previous).

Comment: This is almost there!  In `less`, using '&!<1stpattern>' allows me to 'hide' lines with a pattern on, however it only applies to one pattern at a time, so if I find a second pattern and apply '&!<2ndpattern>', lines that matched the first pattern and were hidden, are now visible.  So very close!

Comment: @forquare: There's a command history that you can access with the up & down arrows keys. So press `&!` and then press an arrow key.

Comment: @forquare: And I just discovered that the history is saved, so your old patterns will be available next time you run `less`; I don't know if it's preserved after rebooting, though.

Comment: It is, the history is stored in `~/.lesshst`. And yes, just group patterns just like you would in grep.

Comment: @orion that was the last bit I was missing - how to concatenate patterns together.  I though I had tried the pipe symbol before and it failed, but now I try again it works!
So:
&!<pattern1>|<pattern2>|<pattern3>
will remove lines with pattern1 or pattern2 or pattern3

Comment: you can also `grep foo | grep -v bar | less`.

Comment: Which version of less is this for? I'm on a Mac and I don't have it :( I've also tried installing the homebrew dupe but no love their either. 

    `$less --version
    less 418
    Copyright (C) 1984-2007 Mark Nudelman

    less comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law. 
    For information about the terms of redistribution,
    see the file named README in the less distribution.
    Homepage: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less`

Comment: I figured it out. Homebrew dupes has the latest version. I just had to kick bash because it wasn't grabbing the right file (even though which told me it was grabbing /user/local/bin/less).

Comment: Man, this should be taught together with the a-b-c.

Comment: After invoking the `&pattern`, is there a way to keep it when invoking `shift f` follow?

Answer (score 14):

Building on [orion's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179240/80216), the [`less(1)` man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/less) describes

> `/pattern`
>
>   Search forward in the file for the
>   *N*
>   -th line
>     containing the
>   `pattern`
>   .
>   *N*
>   <sup>†</sup>
>   defaults to 1. 
>     The
>   `pattern`
>   is a regular expression,
>     as recognized by the regular expression library supplied by your system. 
>     The search starts at the second line displayed
>     (but see the
>   `-a`
>   and
>   `-j`
>   options, which change this).
>
> Certain characters are special
>   if entered at the beginning of the `pattern`;
>   they modify the type of search
>   rather than become part of the `pattern`:
>
> `^N` or `!`
>
>   Search for lines which do NOT match the
>   `pattern`
>   .
>
> `^E` or `*`
>
>   Search multiple files. 
>     That is, if the search reaches the END of the current file
>     without finding a match,
>     the search continues in the next file in the command line list.
>
> `^F` or `@`
>
>   Begin the search
>     at the first line of the FIRST file in the command line list,
>     regardless of what is currently displayed on the screen
>     or the settings of the
>   `-a`
>   or
>   `-j`
>   options.
>
> `^K`
>
>   Highlight any text
>     which matches the
>   `pattern`
>   on the current screen,
>     but don't move to the first match (KEEP current position).
>
> `^R`
>
>   Don't interpret regular expression metacharacters;
>     that is, do a simple textual comparison.
>
> ____________
>   <sup>†</sup> Commands may be preceded by a decimal number,
>   called *N* in the descriptions …

(Of course `^N` and `^E`, etc., represent
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, etc.)

It turns out that `&pattern`
and `/pattern` work well together. 
For example, the commands

- `&!arp|dns`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `/`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>`fail|fatal|fault|sd[a-z][0-9]`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

typed in either order, will hide (exclude) all lines
containing `arp` or `dns` (like `grep -v`), and then, in the remaining lines,
highlight all occurrences of `fail`, `fatal`, `fault`,
or anything that looks like the name of a SCSI device (`sd[a-z][0-9]`). 
Note that lines that contain `arp` or `dns`,
and also `fail` or any of the other danger words,
will ***not*** be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Over the last few months, I have become somewhat enamoured of `fzf`.

In your case, *as long as context is not needed* (i.e., the equivalent of grep's `-A`, `-B`, or `-C` is not needed, and by the way, less's `&` also has the same limitation), then fzf is a very powerful tool.

Here's a silly example:

```
printf "%s\n" {aa,bb,cc}{dd,ee,ff}{gg,hh,ii} | fzf
```

If you run that, and play with inputs like `aa | bb dd | ee !gg !hh` and so on, you will quickly see what is happening.

Fzf's documentation on the `|` operator is sparse, but my best guess is it only applies to the terms immediately before and after, which means, in effect, that OR takes precedence over AND (which is *implicit*; all terms are AND-ed by default).  But in most cases this should not be an issue, and things work out OK in my experience.

Give it a shot.  I have found it surprisingly useful when it comes to browsing things when I am not really sure what I am looking for, and when context does not matter.