# Is it possible to save filtered results from less

Tags: less

Related to: (grep inside of less) [grep inside less?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179238/grep-inside-less)

Related to: (save less to file) https://superuser.com/questions/290908/how-can-i-save-the-current-contents-of-less-to-a-file

When I filter the results typing `&<regex>` and then save the file contains the unfiltered results. Is it possible to save just the filtered results.

Answer (score 0):

After browsing through `man less`, I spotted the following options:

```
-ofilename or --log-file=filename
              Causes less to copy its input to the named file as it is being viewed.  This applies only when the input file is a pipe, not an ordinary file.  If the file already exists, less will  ask  for
              confirmation before overwriting it.

       -Ofilename or --LOG-FILE=filename
              The -O option is like -o, but it will overwrite an existing file without asking for confirmation.

              If  no  log file has been specified, the -o and -O options can be used from within less to specify a log file.  Without a file name, they will simply report the name of the log file.  The "s"
              command is equivalent to specifying -o from within less.
```

So if you do something like `cat big_file.txt | less --log-file=output.txt`, you will get the output of `less` in the output file as you view it.

Comment: Somehow this option does not work. Log file ends up with the same content as the original file. Checked this on version `dpoliaru@host:~$ less --version
less 487 (GNU regular expressions)`